# how data will be transferred from S3 bucket to Spark workers

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, rdd

When we create the RDD using textFile function based on HDFS it will create the partitions according to the blocks and computation will generally happen where the data resides onto the data node.

However, when we create RDD based on S3 files, how data will be transferred from S3 bucket to Spark workers for execution? does transfer involves driver as well? Also will their be any performance implications while using the S3 as storage as compared to HDFS.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: Was the answer informative?

Answer (score 4):

As you imply no data locality with S3.

Just need splitable format for Workers to get data from.

Hence, S3 is slower, but cheaper.

No NameNode req'd.

Driver is only required for things like collect and coordinating tasks to Workers/Executors. Would not make sense architecturally.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does it mean, when we try to load the data from S3 directly in Spark then it will workers who will fetch the data from S3 and do the processing?

Comment: Yes. Some config stuff, look at this post  https://medium.com/@mrpowers/working-with-s3-and-spark-locally-1374bb0a354

Comment: Yes I think I stated that.

Comment: When Spark tries to read the data from S3 where data is present in various files may be because of partitions, then how Spark will get to know about the partitioned files. from where it will get the meta data for the objects present in S3. Also, How workers will get to know which partition or chunk of data needs to be read for processing?